# Доступ к вложенному словарю

Tags: python, json, django

Добрый день, уважаемы знатоки. Изучаю Python и Json.

Есть такое в json файле:

```
{
"рубашка":{"kol": 32, "type": "шт"},
"брюки":{"kol": 22, "type": "шт"},
"носки":{"kol": 60, "type": "пара"},
"трусы":{"kol": 45, "type": "пара"},
"ботинки":{"kol": 21, "type": "пара"},
"кеды":{"kol": 29, "type": "пара"},
"сапоги":{"kol": 28, "type": "пара"},
"шляпа":{"kol": 20, "type": "шт"},
"кепка":{"kol": 14, "type": "шт"},
"пальто":{"kol": 15, "type": "шт"},
"футболка":{"kol": 30, "type": "шт"}
}
```

На выходе декодированный получается:

```
{'шляпа': {'kol': 20, 'type': 'шт'}, 'сапоги': {'kol': 28, 'type': 'пара'}, 'кепка': {'kol': 14, 'type': 'шт'}, 'пальто': {'kol': 15, 'type': 'шт'}, 'футболка': {'kol': 30, 'type': 'шт'}, 'брюки': {'kol': 22, 'type': 'шт'}, 'кеды': {'kol': 29, 'type': 'пара'}, 'носки': {'kol': 60, 'type': 'пара'}, 'ботинки': {'kol': 21, 'type': 'пара'}, 'трусы': {'kol': 45, 'type': 'пара'}, 'рубашка': {'kol': 32, 'type': 'шт'}}
```

Декодирую его. И необходимо посчитать количество штучного товара и парного, и количество всего товаров. Так вот непонятен алгоритм немного, как проверять и получать доступ к вложенному словарю, то есть получит доступ (и проверить) type: 'шт'.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

По ключу:

```
for name_product in parent_dict.keys():
    print(parent_dict[name_product]['type'])
```

Comment: Что то не работает. `import json
myfile = json.load(open('tovar.json', 'r'))
shtuka = 0
para = 0
for key in myfile.keys():
 if 'шт' in key['tip']:
  shtuka +=1
 elif 'пара' in key['tip']:
  para +=1
 else:
  print('Очень сложная АШИПКА!')

print('========================')
print('Количество штучного товара', shtuka)
print('Количество парного товара', para)
print(myfile)`

Comment: Всё. Разобрался спасибо! Тема сработала ваша.

Comment: Спасибо это много, а вот если ответ помог, можно его отметить, как правильный :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [232]: d
Out[232]:
{'ботинки': {'kol': 21, 'type': 'пара'},
 'брюки': {'kol': 22, 'type': 'шт'},
 'кеды': {'kol': 29, 'type': 'пара'},
 'кепка': {'kol': 14, 'type': 'шт'},
 'носки': {'kol': 60, 'type': 'пара'},
 'пальто': {'kol': 15, 'type': 'шт'},
 'рубашка': {'kol': 32, 'type': 'шт'},
 'сапоги': {'kol': 28, 'type': 'пара'},
 'трусы': {'kol': 45, 'type': 'пара'},
 'футболка': {'kol': 30, 'type': 'шт'},
 'шляпа': {'kol': 20, 'type': 'шт'}}

In [233]: from collections import Counter

In [241]: c = Counter(v['type'] for v in d.values())

In [242]: c
Out[242]: Counter({'пара': 5, 'шт': 6})

In [243]: sum(c.values())
Out[243]: 11
```

или, что еще удобнее, использовать [Pandas модуль](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
In [257]: import pandas as pd

In [258]: df = pd.DataFrame(d).T

In [259]: df
Out[259]:
         kol  type
ботинки   21  пара
брюки     22    шт
кеды      29  пара
кепка     14    шт
носки     60  пара
пальто    15    шт
рубашка   32    шт
сапоги    28  пара
трусы     45  пара
футболка  30    шт
шляпа     20    шт

In [260]: df.groupby('type').kol.agg(['sum','size']).reset_index()
Out[260]:
   type  sum  size
0  пара  183     5
1    шт  133     6
```